# Open google play store when push notification opened

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, react-native

I am setting up firebase push notifications to notify users if there is new update to react native application. The thing is I want to open play store when a push notification opened.

I tried using react native linking. It worked when app is in foreground but when app is in background when push notification opened it will open the app and directed to play store.

```
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications()
   .onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
        Linking.openURL("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sample.myapp");
    });

const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
if (notificationOpen) {
    const { title, body,path } = notificationOpen.notification;
    Linking.openURL('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sample.myapp');
}
```

So is there away to open play store without opening the app in background when push notification is opened?